# Why isn't this submitting to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, registration

```
 <?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="ureviewdu"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="Student"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

/* Obliterate bad input */
$secUser = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reguser']);
$badpasses = $_POST['regpass'];
$salt = '~Z`!@#$%I^&*()_-+Q=}]{[\|"><';
$secPass = md5($badpasses.$salt);

$sql = "INSERT INTO Student (uname, pass, fname, lname, email, currGrade)                VALUES('$secUser','$secPass','$_POST[regfirst]','$_POST[reglast]','$_POST[regemail]','$_POST[regclassrank]')";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result) {
    echo "Thanks for signing up!";
} else {
    echo "Failed.";
}


?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="inc/register/register.php" method="post" id="userRegistration">
        <div class="cen"><h5>User Credentials</h5></div>
        <div class="field required">
        Username: <input type="text" name="reguser" tabindex="1" /><br />
        </div>
        <div class="field required">
        Password: <input type="password" name="regpass" tabindex="2" /><br />
        </div>

        <div class="cen"><h5>User Details</h5></div>
        <div class="field required">
        First Name:<input type="text" name="regfirst"  tabindex="3" /><br />
        </div>
        <div class="field required">
        Last Name:<input type="text" name="reglast"  tabindex="4" /><br />
        </div>
        <div class="field required">
        Email:<input type="text" name="regemail" tabindex="5" /><br />
        </div>
        <div class="field required">
        Current Class:<select name="regclassrank"  tabindex="6">
        <option disabled="disabled">Select Class</option>
            <option value="1">Freshman</option>
            <option value="2">Sophomore</option>
            <option value="3">Pre-Junior</option>
            <option value="4">Junior</option>
            <option value="5">Senior</option>
        <option></option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="cen"><input type="submit" name="submitUser" /></div>
</form>
```

Does anyone see anything wrong with this? It submits fine, but then nothing is INSERTED into the database....

Comment: '$_POST[regfirst]' should be '${_POST['regfirst']}' .. you should also use mysql_real_escape_string or htmlentities on the post variables before inserting into the database, as was mentioned below, SQL Injection

Comment: Change `$result = mysql_query($sql);` to `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` and see what it says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must execute the query with `mysql_query`.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Student (uname, pass, fname, lname, email, currGrade)                VALUES('$secUser','$secPass','$_POST[regfirst]','$_POST[reglast]','$_POST[regemail]','$_POST[regclassrank]')";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result) {
    echo "Thanks for signing up!";
} else {
    echo "There was an error processing your request. Please try again.";
}
```

Comment: See updated php, this automatically says 'failed' upon submission

Comment: You barely beat me to the punch. removing my answer since you said the same thing... :p

Comment: @user700070 You can use echo the result of `mysql_error()` to view the error, but it is most probably an error with your query. See the comment that was posted to your question by Adam MacDonald.

Comment: That worked! Can you show me where to add sql to check if a username that is trying to be registered is ALREADY registered? Please?

Comment: Sure. Take a  look at [this](http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-PHP-MySQL-Novice-Professional/dp/1590595521).

Answer (score 1):

You're creating an SQL string (in the worst way) that will permit SQL Injection (A security problem), then you assign it to a variable '$sql'.

That's it. I don't see you using that string in any other fashion. You're certainly not submitting it to mysql.

Comment: I need some code to show me what you mean and what im doing wrong,

Comment: Latest question indeed shows that the sql string is queried, this is now a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use PDO...

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="ureviewdu"; // Database name
$tbl_name="Student"; // Table name

$return='';

if(isset($_POST)){
    $continue=true;

    if(empty($_POST['reguser']) || strlen($_POST['reguser']) < 3){$continue=false;}
    if(empty($_POST['regpass']) || strlen($_POST['regpass']) < 6){$continue=false;}
    if(empty($_POST['regfirst']) || strlen($_POST['regfirst']) < 3){$continue=false;}
    if(empty($_POST['reglast']) || strlen($_POST['reglast']) < 3){$continue=false;}
    if(empty($_POST['regemail']) || filter_var($_POST['regemail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)==false){$continue=false;}
    if(empty($_POST['regclassrank']) || is_int($_POST['regclassrank'])==false){$continue=false;}

    if($continue===true){
        //Attempt to insert
        try{
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);

            /*** set the error reporting attribute ***/
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            /*** variables ***/
            foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
                if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                    $value = stripslashes($value);
                }
                $values[$key]=$value;
            }
            /*** prepare the SQL statement ***/
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO $tbl_name (uname, pass, fname, lname, email, currGrade)
                               VALUES(:uname,:upass,:fname,:lname,:email,:currGrade)");

            /*** bind the paramaters ***/
            $salt = '~Z`!@#$%I^&*()_-+Q=}]{[\|"><';

            $stmt->bindParam(':uname', $values['reguser']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':upass', sha1($salt.$values['regpass']));
            $stmt->bindParam(':fname', $values['regfirst']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':lname', $values['reglast']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $values['regemail']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':currGrade', (int)$values['regclassrank']);

            /*** execute the prepared statement ***/
            $stmt->execute();

            $return='Thanks for signing up!';

            /*** close the database connection ***/
            $dbh = null;

        }catch(PDOException $e){
            $return='Failed:'. $e->getMessage();
        }

    }else{
        $return='All fields are required';
    }

}

echo $return.

'<form ...........';


?>
```

Comment: Upvoting this because it shows how to avoid SQL Injection, and answers the question.